# display contents in different languages

Tags: android

Currently, I have a txt file that is formatted (using delimiters) in a specific way. I read the file, parse it and populate the GUI of the app.

I need to make the multi-lingual app so basically display non English characters. I have 2 ideas in mind:

- Write the file in non English and read it/parse it based on the mobile language.
- In the English file, I change the actual contents to be reference to String ID. These ID are the ones in String.xml. When I read the file, I parse the ID and call the corresponding string. I will let Android figure out the system language and pick the appropriate String.xml
- OR completely different solution that you recommend

Comment: No need to build this, it's a platform feature: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I read the question again, let me elaborate: You'd put the default strings into `res/values/strings.xml` (which should probably be english). Then, for any other language, you create a `values-[language_identifier]`-folder with it's own `strings.xml` file, which contains the translated strings with **the same id's** as the ones in the default language file. You can then reference them by their ID and Android will figure out which language-file to take them from, based on the devices current locale.

Comment: Lukas, I totally know about localization as shown in my second bullet. I am saying that I need to use external file content because the whole logic of the app depends on the file contents. That file defines how "tree structure" look like so it has nodes with and relations. Also it has Values for each node. That's why I am not sure on the way to proceed

Comment: The values are identifiers or localized strings? Do you have any control over the files?

Comment: I have full control over the files. I can even change the structure if needed. File format is almost like  Node1 ID; Node2 ID; Node3 ID; Node1 Value1; Node1 Value2.   So as you can see , it shows the top node, the left/right child, while Value1 and Value 2 are the contents to be displayed and supposed to be in different language. The file will have 10s of lines like that. I

Comment: So there is one ID-Node with n Value-Nodes, where each value-node holds a string in a given language? Can you add an example (with some actual values) to your question?

Comment: @Lukas , yes except that all the nodes will be in one language. So I am thinking if the user choses English, then I load the English file. If he choses German, I load the German file..etc An example of string is 1;2;3;This is node1;this is node2;this is node3